# How to write a unit test an Express controller using Jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I am pretty new to Jest and unit testing for that matter, so before I begin writing unit tests for my controller functions, I wanted to check my understanding. So high level, I understand that the unit test is to test whether the controller function behaves as expected when called.

How would I go about writing a Jest unit test for the following code? I would really appreciate an example so that I can reference it as I write the jest tests for the other controllers. Thank you.

```
//retrieveMember.js


const debug = require('debug')('get_member');
const MemberService = require('../services/MemberService');
const generateError = require('../lib/generateError');


const retrieveMember = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.params.id === ""
    || req.params.id === undefined) {
      throw generateError(400, "invalid.");
    }

    const regex = RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]");
    if (regex.test(req.params.id)) {
      throw generateError(400, "invalid format.");
    }

    const memberId = req.params.id;
    const memberRecord = await MemberService.retrieveOneMember(memberId);

    const member_detail = {
      id: memberRecord.id,
      username: memberRecord.username,
    };

    res.status(200).send({member_detail: member_detail});
  } catch (e) {
    if (e) {
      debug('could not get member');
      return next(e);
    }
  }
};


module.exports = retrieveMember;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`retrieveMember.js`:

```js
const debug = console.debug;
const MemberService = require('./MemberService');
const generateError = require('./generateError');

const retrieveMember = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.params.id === '' || req.params.id === undefined) {
      throw generateError(400, 'invalid.');
    }

    const regex = RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9-]');
    if (regex.test(req.params.id)) {
      throw generateError(400, 'invalid format.');
    }

    const memberId = req.params.id;
    const memberRecord = await MemberService.retrieveOneMember(memberId);

    const member_detail = {
      id: memberRecord.id,
      username: memberRecord.username,
    };

    res.status(200).send({ member_detail: member_detail });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e) {
      debug('could not get member');
      return next(e);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = retrieveMember;
```

`MemberService.js`:

```js
const MemberService = {
  async retrieveOneMember() {
    return 'real data';
  },
};

module.exports = MemberService;
```

`generateError.js`:

```js
function generateError(status, message) {
  return new Error(message);
}

module.exports = generateError;
```

`retrieveMember.test.js`:

```js
const retrieveMember = require('./retrieveMember');
const MemberService = require('./MemberService');

describe('61834610', () => {
  it('should throw 400 error if id is empty string', async () => {
    const mReq = { params: { id: '' } };
    const mRes = {};
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await retrieveMember(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(mNext).toBeCalledWith(new Error('invalid.'));
  });

  it('should throw 400 error if id is undefined', async () => {
    const mReq = { params: {} };
    const mRes = {};
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await retrieveMember(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(mNext).toBeCalledWith(new Error('invalid.'));
  });

  it('should throw 400 error if id is invalid format', async () => {
    const mReq = { params: { id: '$$' } };
    const mRes = {};
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await retrieveMember(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(mNext).toBeCalledWith(new Error('invalid format.'));
  });

  it('should retrieve one member by id and send response correctly', async () => {
    const mMemberRecord = { id: '1', username: 'KF1' };
    jest.spyOn(MemberService, 'retrieveOneMember').mockResolvedValueOnce(mMemberRecord);
    const mReq = { params: { id: '1' } };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await retrieveMember(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(MemberService.retrieveOneMember).toBeCalledWith('1');
    expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(200);
    expect(mRes.send).toBeCalledWith({ member_detail: { id: '1', username: 'KF1' } });
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61834610/retrieveMember.test.js (9.346s)
  61834610
    ✓ should throw 400 error if id is empty string (18ms)
    ✓ should throw 400 error if id is undefined (2ms)
    ✓ should throw 400 error if id is invalid format (1ms)
    ✓ should retrieve one member by id and send response correctly (1ms)

  console.debug
    could not get member

      at stackoverflow/61834610/retrieveMember.js:27:7

  console.debug
    could not get member

      at stackoverflow/61834610/retrieveMember.js:27:7

  console.debug
    could not get member

      at stackoverflow/61834610/retrieveMember.js:27:7

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |   95.83 |     87.5 |      75 |   95.45 |                   
 MemberService.js  |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 3                 
 generateError.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 retrieveMember.js |     100 |     87.5 |     100 |     100 | 26                
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.539s
```

Comment: Thank you! Your response is very much appreciated. I am actually using typescript and exporting default MemberService, so I had to use `MemberService.default` instead of `MemberService` as the param for the functions `jest.spyOn()` and `expect()`. I was not familiar with `.mockReturnThis()`, but now understand that it should be used in the case of methods that are typically chained (and thus always need to return this).

Comment: @surferwat Yes. `.mockReturnThis()` will return `this` context so you can chain call methods.

Comment: @slideshowp2 can you please explain why you use mockReturnThis() only in status of mReq and not on json? Thank you you example is pure gold :)

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis Because the `.send()` method is the last method of the chained calls. After it, there are no more chained calls, so you don't need to return the context.

Comment: @slideshowp2 What do you mean by context, is it the jest object? even in jest documentation it doesn't provide much info about .mockReturnThis(). Thanks for explaining it is good enough to make my example work but I would also like to understand it lol.

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis  The `this` context is `mRes` object itself.